# Policy function π in Reinforcement learning unclear

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-mining, pattern-recognition, learning-theory

I have one question about policy function in Reinforcement learning.

> > in fact this function indicates which action should be done in each state? Or
> >
> > this function indicate for get the specific reward in each state, which action shoud be selected?
> >
> > or something else?

Answer (score 1):

A policy $\pi$ maps each state to an action.  Generalizations of this allow for a stochastic mapping (each state to an action with given probability).  Given a policy you can estimate or compute the expected reward (or cost) at any state.  An optimal policy is simply one that produces the most reward overall.